# Word for children that have a babysitter or au pair

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, translation

In Dutch a babysitter is called an "oppas". This gave rise to the word "oppaskinderen" which translates literally to "babysitter children".

As far as I could research, there is no single English word for this. Is there any combination of words that convey the same and doesn't sound like crap?

**Example sentence**
Dutch: "Hoe gaat het met de *oppaskinderen*?"
English: "How are the *[babysitter children]* doing?"

Comment: Who is the Dutch question asked of?

Comment: Do you mean who asked the question? If so, it is irrelevant I think, it can be a friend of someone who babysits for example.

Comment: No, I mean who is it asked of (that is, who is it who answers the question)?

Comment: It is asked of someone who babysits/is an au pair. It doesn't make sense to ask it to someone else in Dutch, since you wouldn't refer to someone's own children as "oppaskinderen".

Comment: short of using the artificial "the babysat children", you could be specific: "how are the children you babysit/take care of doing?" or simply, if there is enough context: "how are the children?".

Comment: Based upon the children that I have seen with an au pair, "spawn of Satan" seems appropriate.

Comment: Though I upvoted mplungjan's answer as "charges" is the most correct of the answers, context is as important as the word choice, IMO.  If the babysitter has no children of their own and someone asks "How are the kids?", I believe it would be generally understood that the person is asking about the babysat children.  If the babysitter has their own children, it could be phrased like this, "How goes the babysitting?"  Of course, my personal favorite, regardless of whose kids they are is, "How are the rugrats?". :-)

Comment: I agree that to get a better answer, you need to provide more details. Is an *oppaskinderen* a permanent label? As in, used to describe anyone whose primary caregiver was a non-parent/relative/guardian? (Only English label of this type that springs to mind is a [bottle-baby](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/bottle%20baby).) Or does the label only apply while the children are being cared for by a babysitter/nanny? A sample answer and explanation of the asnwerer would help your dialog as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How are your [charges](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge) doing?

comes to mind as

*a person or thing committed to the care of another*

Comment: +1 I like _charges_ although it seems very formal and it would have to be in context (not asked of someone with a string of court appearances ahead of them)

Comment: While formally correct (so +1) I cannot imagine anyone using such a phrase in a normal conversation without getting a funny look.

Comment: Hehe. I agree. Sounds very Dickensian. How are the little brats/monsters doing would be more contemporary

Comment: I'd find this less unnatural with a possessive, ie "How are your charges doing?" or "How are Jean's charges doing?"  I can't recall ever having heard this usage of the word "charge" without a possessive.

Comment: Sounds more like something from a Schwarzenegger movie.

Comment: "Charges" is the closest I can come up with, and it only makes sense when used in context. I don't think English has a single word which reliably expresses the requested concept.

Comment: Very formal, but I like it!

Answer (score 2):

*babysittee* is a word I've seen a few times but it is not in any dictionary and I doubt it's commonly used. I guess it sounds like crap anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I already heard the terms "[**critter**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=critter)" and "**monster**" used that way.

> "How are the (little) **critters** doing?"
>
> "How are the little **monsters** doing?"

Comment: I've heard people refer to their own children that way. My parents variously called me *rugrat*, *ankle-biter*, *knee-biter*, *yard-ape* and probably a few more I'm forgetting.